# jquery code if pasting the same code is not alerting the user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code where my codes are generated dynamically through a function call in in the input field, I am using coldfusion for it

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" class="form-control required" required placeholder="Voucher Code" name="voucherCode" id="voucherCode" value="#generateVoucherCode()#"/>
```

now i have the jquery code which checks for the duplicate of the same vouchercode if it has been there or not

Here is my JS Code

```
$(document).on('input paste focusout', '#voucherCode', function() {
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'update.cfm?action=checkcode',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { voucherCode: inputValue },
    success: function(response) {
      var r = $.trim(response);
      var chkTrue = (r === 'exists');
      if (chkTrue) {
        swal({
            title: "Hmm!",
            text: "Voucher Code already exists",
            type: "warning"
        });
        $(".delButtonSpac").attr('disabled',true);
        return false;

      } else {
        $(this).addClass('valid').removeClass('error');
        $(".delButtonSpac").attr('disabled',false);
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      $(".verror").css('display','block').html('Error occurred during AJAX call');
    }
  });
});
```

when i paste an existing code , it shows me a message, but when i paste again an item and add some spaces in fronty of it,  it just ignores and add it to the backend.

like, if there is code as: `red` and i just add some spaces to it like          `red`, it skips the check and does not show the swal and just sends to the backend for insert which is wrong

Comment: Your `update.cfm` should be applying the trim - not sure the relevance of showing us the code for the response (after it's happened).   You could add the trim before sending it, but that's not secure, `var inputValue = $(this).val().trim();`

Comment: problem is when i paste it, it shows alert, but when i modify it by adding spaces in front of end, it ignores and move ahead

Comment: I see that you have a `return false;` inside the `success:` callback - this is returning to the ajax call and *does nothing*.  If you're trying to cancel the event, then you need to return false in the event itself.  It's only possible to allude to what you're trying to do given the small sample of code without the bigger picture.

Comment: anyway as said somehow already, you are expecting the input data to be processed by the callback invoked after such data was sent to the server (`success: function(response)`).  the input data sent is specified here instead `data: { voucherCode: inputValue },` and you are not changing it anyhow before sending it. The callback as a whole will be invoked anytime any of those events `input paste focusout'` occurs. If you wanted to make sure just put a `console.log` before setting `inputValue '